# Speed/Duplex auto-negotiation suddenly stopped working

Tags: windows-7, internet, network-adapter

Today my internet suddenly stopped working and the network adapter started cycling between "Network cable unplugged" and "enabled".

I googled the issued and some people suggested to modify the Speed & Duplex settings to 10 mbps.

I tried and 10 mbps full duplex is the only setting that worked. However, now the internet is a lot slower than it used to be.

What causes auto-negotiation to suddenly stop working?

Network adapter: Broadcom NetLink (TM) Gigabit Ethernet

Comment: what is the other end of the cable is plugged into? a router, or ISP equipment like a cablemodem? if its a router, are you able to login to it?

Comment: It's a router, and the wifi functionality works like normal. I am able to log in but don't see any settings for speed and duplex. It is a netgear smartwizard thing. Model WNR2000v2

Comment: in Maintenance -> Router Status -> Show Statistics, does the Status column say 10Mbps/Full, or 100Mbps/Full? Here is a link to your routers manual: http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/WNR2000V2/WNR2000v2_UM_15JAN2010.pdf .  update your PCs chipset and nic drivers, and check to make sure your cable is Cat5 or better, and has no sharp angles or is folded over tightly on its run. try a differant port on the lan switch. reboot both devices.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, but I ended up figuring out that the ethernet cable was just faulty. I tried a new one and it works now.